# Passing message from one window to another window

Tags: html, api, postmessage

I'm trying to pass the message from `comn.html` window to `comm.html` window, but it doesn't pass
please tell me whether the code is correct or not. If not, kindly provide the exact code for that.
I want the code for passing message between windows not between iframes.

Code of `comn.html`:

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

window.onload = function() 
{
var btn = document.getElementById('send');
btn.addEventListener('click', function sendMessage(e)
{
var string="Hi Adaptavant";
var new_win=window.open('comm.html');
new_win.postMessage(string,"*");
});
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="send" >Send Message</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of `comm.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>postMessage</title>
<script type=text/javascript>

window.onload = function()
{
var msg = document.getElementById('message');
window.addEventListener("message",function receiveMessage(e) {
msg.innerHTML="msg received= " +e.data;
document.write("the message is " +msg);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run this program, my message isn't posting in another window.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

replace your script with this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
var msg = document.getElementById('message');
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var message = e.data;
  msg.innerHTML="msg received= " +e.data;
});
}
```

Let me know if it worked!